# Can a route be included in more than one destination ticket?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

The rules that come with the game do not specifically state the a route (between two cities) can be included in more than one destination string, but this is assumed when we play.

**Is that a correct assumption?**

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to BCGSE.  You might want to try and make the title of your question have more information about the question itself, instead of just the name of the game.  You had two questions that looked identical on the main page because they had the same title.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. The section about scoring says:

> Players should then reveal all their Destination Tickets and add (or subtract) the value of their Destination Tickets still in hand, based on whether
>   they successfully (or not) connected those cities together.

So the only thing that matters is whether those cities are connected to each other. It's very possible that all your routes will share a single link across the middle of the country, and that's fine.

Comment: I'd go even further: potential reuse of the routes for multiple tickets is main strategical objective when you draw tickets

Comment: To put it another way: all that matters is that at the time you score the route card, your network of track connects the two cities on each card. In some versions, it's possible to have the same route multiple times; they all can use the same chunks of track. In versions with stations, the station has to be used for one specific chunk of track, but all routes can use that one track "borrowed" using the station. We place the station over it to indicate its use during the "proving" of one's tickets' completion.